# SSRS 2008R2 Expression to limit text

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a tabular report that pulls in a field that shows free text. By adding:

=Left(fields!data.value,250)  I can limit the number of characters to 250. However what I would really like to do is end the text after the last full stop (period) closest to 250 characters.

Eg, at the moment the report may display: 'Sales reached 25,000 for September. We are planning' and end abruptly at 'planning' as 'planning'is where 250 characters end.

Ideally I would like the text to end at the end of the sentence before, eg to stop after 'September'.

Do you know if this is possible - any suggestions or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

With many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `InStrRev` to get the last period in the string, and use this as a parameter for the `Left` expression.

There are also a few more checks to consider, such as:

- When there are no periods in the string
- When there are no periods in the first 250 characters
- When there are periods after the 250 character cut off as well as periods in the first 250 characters.

This should work and catch most of the exceptions I can think of:

```
=IIf(InStrRev(Left(Fields!data.Value, 250), ".") > 0
        And InStrRev(Left(Fields!data.Value, 250), ".") <= 250
    , Left(Fields!data.Value, InStrRev(Left(Fields!data.Value, 250), "."))
    , Left(Fields!data.Value, 250))
```

Comment: Your welcome! If an answer solved your issue, please consider setting it as accepted. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work